# Edit the Button "onclick" function depending on Selected Value

Tags: javascript, html

When someone clicks on the "Submit" button I would like it to call a function that is currently selected on the 'paymentMethod' option group box.

For example if I selected the Bitcoin option it will call the bitcoin() function and the button will look like this: 
`<button onclick='bitcoin()' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>`

My code:

```
<select class="form-control select2" id='paymentMethod'>

                          <optgroup label="Crypto">
                                <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin, Etherum, Litecoin, DogeCoin, Ripple, ETC</option>
                                   </optgroup>


                                   <optgroup label="Paypal">
                                   <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
                                   </optgroup>

                                   <optgroup label="Giftcard">
                                   <option value="Giftcard">Amazon, PSN, Steam, Battle.Net, G2A, ETC</option>
                                   </optgroup>

    </select>

 <button onclick='//I want this to be whatever is selected in paymentMethod option group' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
```

I tried this JS code:

```
                         <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paymentMethod').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'Paypal')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        var paymentEr = 'Paypal()';
      }
      else if (this.value == 'Giftcard')
      {
        var paymentEr = 'Giftcard()';
      } else {
          var paymentEr = 'Paypal()';
      }
    });
});

    document.write("<button onclick=' + paymentEr + "' class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>");
    </script>
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that you tried?

Comment: Added JS code I've tried.

Comment: **Never** use `document.write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than change the onClick handler itself, I would make one handler that handles all of the cases (or if you want to have separate functions to organize your code, simply call those functions within the relevant condition blocks as follows):

```js
function handleForm() {
  
  const selected = document.getElementById("paymentMethod").value;
  
  if (selected === 'Bitcoin') {
    //handle bitcoin
  }
  else if (selected === 'Paypal') {
    //handle Paypal
  }
  else if (selected === 'Giftcard') {
    //handle GiftCard
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control select2" id='paymentMethod'>
  <optgroup label="Crypto">
    <option value="Bitcoin">
      Bitcoin, Etherum, Litecoin, DogeCoin, Ripple, ETC
    </option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Paypal">
    <option value="Paypal">
      Paypal
    </option>
  </optgroup>
  
  <optgroup label="Giftcard">
    <option value="Giftcard">
      Amazon, PSN, Steam, Battle.Net, G2A, ETC
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<button onclick='handleForm()' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

On button `click` it checks the select element for the selected value and you can **avoid** inline javascript in the html code.Check my answer.

```js
function init(){
  
         let el =  document.getElementById("paymentMethod");

         let sbmBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

         sbmBtn.addEventListener('click',getSelectedValue);
         
         function getSelectedValue(){
            
            let selectedVal = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;

            if (selectedVal == 'Paypal'){
                    //var paymentEr = 'Paypal()';
                    alert(selectedVal);
            }else if (selectedVal == 'Giftcard'){
                    //var paymentEr = 'Giftcard()';
                    alert(selectedVal);
            } else {
                    //var paymentEr = 'Paypal()';
                    alert(selectedVal);
            }
         }
}

//DOM has been loaded
addEventListener('load',init);
```

```html
<select class="form-control select2" id='paymentMethod'>

        <optgroup label="Crypto">
              <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin, Etherum, Litecoin, DogeCoin, Ripple, ETC</option>
                 </optgroup>


                 <optgroup label="Paypal">
                 <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
                 </optgroup>

                 <optgroup label="Giftcard">
                 <option value="Giftcard">Amazon, PSN, Steam, Battle.Net, G2A, ETC</option>
                 </optgroup>

</select>
<button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
```